# How add data in existing ajax json result

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel, I have defined two models Category and Subcategory.
To fetch data I am using ajax.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
      {{ Form::select('category_id',[''=>'-select a category-']+$categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'category']) }}
  </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
{{ Form::select('subcategory_id',[''=>'-select a Subcategory-'], null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'subcategory']) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This are my Script

```
<script>
    $('#category').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var cat_id = e.target.value;
        //ajax

        $.get('/ajax-subcat?cat_id='+cat_id, function(data){
            //subcategory
            $('#subcategory').empty();
            $.each(data,function(index, subcatObj){
$('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
            })
        })
    });

</script>
```

Here is how I am getting subcategories from a category

```
ROute::get("/ajax-subcat", function (){
$cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
$subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id',$cat_id)->get();

return Response::json($subcategories);

});
```

Now in the frontend if I select cat1 from category drop down, I can get output `subcat1, subcat2,subcat3` in the subcategory drop down serially by query the selected category. Its fine and working good.

But when I select a category, the first subcategory has been selected automatically. I want no subcategory will selected automatically. There will be first -select a sub category- which value will be null and rest of the subcategories will be then.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you ..

```
<script>
     $('#category').on('change',function(e){
      console.log(e);
      var cat_id = e.target.value;
       //ajax

      $.get('/ajax-subcat?cat_id='+cat_id, function(data){
         //subcategory
        $('#subcategory').empty();
        $('#subcategory').append($("<option></option>").val("").html("--Select Sub Category--"));
        $.each(data,function(index, subcatObj){
       $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: This is perfect and my issue solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad the issue is fixed. Please upvote and close the issue so others can benefit.

Comment: Hi, I can not find out the upvote and close issue option. Can you please help me to figure out it and how can i do it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow